# .tokenize() behaviour difference in Tokenizer using various pre-trained models in HuggingFace on Chinese sentences

Tags: nlp, huggingface-tokenizers

I am testing the functionality of Tokenizer using various pre-trained models on Chinese sentences. Here are my codes:

```
from transformers import BartTokenizer, BertTokenizer

text_eng = 'I go to school by train.'
text_can = '我乘搭火車上學。'
text_chi = '我搭火車返學。'

tokenizer_bartchinese = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('fnlp/bart-base-chinese')
tokenizer_bertchinese = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-chinese')
tokenizer_fb = BartTokenizer.from_pretrained('facebook/bart-large') 

# BART Chinese
print(tokenizer_bartchinese.tokenize(text_eng))
print(tokenizer_bartchinese.tokenize(text_can))
print(tokenizer_bartchinese.tokenize(text_chi))

# BERT Chinese
print(tokenizer_bertchinese.tokenize(text_eng))
print(tokenizer_bertchinese.tokenize(text_can))
print(tokenizer_bertchinese.tokenize(text_chi))

# BART Large
print(tokenizer_fb.tokenize(text_eng))
print(tokenizer_fb.tokenize(text_can))
print(tokenizer_fb.tokenize(text_chi))
```

Here are the results:

```
['I', 'go', 'to', 'school', 'by', 'train', '.']
['我', '乘', '搭', '火', '車', '上', '學', '。']
['我', '搭', '火', '車', '返', '學', '。']
['[UNK]', 'go', 'to', 'school', 'by', 't', '##rain', '.']
['我', '乘', '搭', '火', '車', '上', '學', '。']
['我', '搭', '火', '車', '返', '學', '。']
['I', 'Ġgo', 'Ġto', 'Ġschool', 'Ġby', 'Ġtrain', '.']
['æĪ', 'ĳ', 'ä¹', 'ĺ', 'æ', 'Ĳ', 'Ń', 'ç', 'ģ«', 'è»', 'Ĭ', 'ä¸Ĭ', 'åŃ', '¸', 'ãĢĤ']
['æĪ', 'ĳ', 'æ', 'Ĳ', 'Ń', 'ç', 'ģ«', 'è»', 'Ĭ', 'è¿', 'Ķ', 'åŃ', '¸', 'ãĢĤ']
```

Should the Tokenizer recognize vocabulary in Chinese, such that the Tokenizer will segment the vocabulary instead of splitting each character? For example, 火車 (train) in Chinese is a vocabulary; and it should not be split into 火(fire) and 車(car).

My expected behaviour:

```
['我', '乘搭', '火車', '上', '學', '。']
```

which translates (just for reference):

```
['I', 'ride', 'train', 'to', 'school', '.']
```

Also, I noticed that `facebook/bart-large` generates weird characters (the last 3 lines of the code output). Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: A tokenizer follows an algorithm and is trained on text. That means you can't just look at `火車` and say that the tokenizer is incorrect. The result is correct considering the training data. It might not be the most optimal choice, but the corresponding model has learnt to treat `'火', '車'` as `train` when they are consecutive in a sequence. `bart-large` uses a byte-level BPE algorithm (i.e. the output is correct).

Comment: Therefore, do you mean that even with pre-trained Chinese LLM, I also need to further train the vocabulary in order to let the tokenizer recognize the vocabulary like `火車` (train)?

Comment: No, that is not required because the model will take care of it.